# Possible to have variables in migration configuration?

Tags: 8, migrations

We are running a continuous migration (using migrate_plus) from a JSON API which supports `last_modified_since` as a query parameter. I would like to run this job every hour, and use the time of the previous run as parameter.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I tried tried overriding the variable by adding to the `$config` array in settings.php, but that is probably not even supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! However, depending on the plugin you are using, it might be picky about what you put *in* the variable. Here are two examples of variables being used in a migration config:

**A file import**

```
source:

  plugin: csv
  track_changes: true
  path: 'public://migration/csv/image_download.csv'
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - image

  fields:
    image: 'Image'
    media_name: 'Media name'

  constants:
    uri_file: 'public://photos'

process:
  uri_file:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/uri_file
        - media_name

  uid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1

  filename: display_name 

  uri:
    plugin: download
    source:
      - image
      - '@uri_file'
```

In the above, both `constants/uri_file` established in the "source" step of the migration, and `uri_file` passed as `@uri_file` to the download plugin in "process" step are variables.

The documentation for the migrate_plus process plugin "merge" has another good example:

```
source:
     plugin: d7_node
   process:
     temp_body:
       plugin: iterator
       source: field_section
       process:
         target_id:
           plugin: migration
           migration: field_collection_field_section_to_paragraph
           source: value
     temp_images:
       plugin: iterator
       source: field_image
       process
         target_id:
           plugin: migration
           migration: image_entities_to_paragraph
           source: fid
     paragraphs_field:
       plugin: merge
       source:
         - @temp_body
         - @temp_images
   destination:
     plugin: 'entity:node'
```

In both these example, the vars are used in arrays. That's just what the plugin expects, not something inherent to using variables.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I had completely overlooked this! In your examples, it looks like the variables are all "internal to" the migration (created in one source, and given to the field as a source).

In my case, I would like to have a variable in the url, it is now like this: 

https://api.hel.fi/linkedevents/v1/event?publisher=ytj:0586977-6,ahjo:46501&include=location,keywords&page_size=100&start=today

And I would like to add `last_modified_since=@time-of-last-migration`, which could be the highWater field.

Comment: Ah, my apologies I misunderstood. In this case, you will probably have to write a small custom source plugin to capture that piece of the url for use in the migration. There _might_ be an existing plugin that could do this, but given the specificity you will need, a custom plugin is probably the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll try that as soon as I find the time and get back to you.